# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{12^n\cdot(n!)^5}{(n^2+n)^{2n}\cdot(n+1)^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, factorial

> Evaluate the following limit: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{12^n\cdot(n!)^5}{(n^2+n)^{2n}\cdot(n+1)^n}$$

The factorial function is creating a problem for me here. I can manage all other terms (by clubbing them together) but what to do with the factorial function.

I also thought of taking logarithm on both sides after assuming the limit as $y$ but that didn't help me much.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe Stirling asymptotic formula?

Comment: @DavidRaveh if I recall correctly, I've just heard of this thing, i guess it's kind of an approximation...but I don't know how to use it

Comment: The denominator is asymptotically $n^{5n}=(n^n)^5$. Not sure whether this helps.

Comment: $(n!)^5\sim(2\pi n)^{\frac{5}{2}}e^{-5n}n^{5n}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Stirling formula can be avoided. We will rely on elementary methods. We have $$b_n:=\frac{12^n\cdot(n!)^5}{(n^2+n)^{2n}\cdot(n+1)^n}\le {12^n(n!)^5\over n^{5n}}=\left [{12^{n/5}n!\over n^n}\right]^5=:a_n^5$$ Next $${a_{n+1}\over a_n}=12^{1/5}\left (1+{1\over n}\right )^{-n}\le 12^{1/5}2^{-1}<16^{1/5}2^{-1}=2^{-1/5}$$ Therefore $a_n\to 0,$ which implies $b_n\to 0.$ On the way we have used $$\left (1+{1\over n}\right )^n\ge 1+n{1\over n}=2$$
**Remark**
The Stirling formula can be useful if we replace $12$ with $e^5.$ Indeed analyzing the proof we observe that ${a_{n+1}\over a_n}\to 1,$ which is inconclusive. If we apply the Stirling formula then
$$a_n={e^nn!\over n^n}\approx \sqrt{2\pi n}\to \infty$$ and
$${ a_n^5\over b_n}=\left (1+{1\over n}\right )^{3n}\to e^3$$ Hence $b_n\to \infty.$

Comment: A slight variation on this argument:
the inequality $(1+1/n)^n\geqslant2$ implies by induction on $n$
that $n^n\geqslant2^{n-1}n!$ for all $n\geqslant1.$ Hence
$$
\frac{12^n(n!)^5}{(n^2+n)^{2n}(n+1)^n} \leqslant
12^n\left(\frac{n!}{n^n}\right)^5 \leqslant \frac{12^n}{32^{n-1}} =
32\left(\frac38\right)^n \to 0 \text { as } n\to\infty.
$$

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Your inequality is contained in $a_{n+1}^5/a_n^5 \le 12/2^5=3/8,$ proved on the way in the answer.

Comment: (+1) I would note that Stirling's formula gives us a quick way to guess what the limit is; once this is known, proving it with inequalities is for sure the way to go.

Comment: @DavidRaveh Thanks for upvoting.. The key method was to study the ratio of two consecutive terms. It is efficient for expressions containing factorials. The estimates were used to simplify the formulas.

Answer (score 2):

[Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) is an asymptotic expression for the factorial,
$$n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right).$$
We can safely ignore the polynomial terms; giving us asymptotically
$$\frac{12^nn^{5n}e^{-5n}}{n^{5n}}\to0$$

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, you can use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation):
$$\frac{12^n(n!)^5}{(n^2+n)^{2n}(n+1)^n}\sim \frac{12^nn^{5n}e^{-5n}(2\pi n)^{5/2}}{(n+1)^{3n}n^{2n}}=\frac{12^n(2\pi n)^{5/2}}{e^{5n}}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{3n}\to 0 $$